# Is there a way to override or change php/laravel request validate status code?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, http-status-codes

As you all may know, when we use laravel validate() function, the error status code it throws is 422. Is there a way to override or change the status code to 400?

`$request->validate([ 'title' => 'required|unique:posts' ]);`

With this code, when error occur, that status code it return is 422, and I want to change that to 400.

I have tried checking manually with if else, but I want to make use of the validate function because it's such a great feature.

Comment: The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions.

Comment: Thanks, your answer gave me a lot more insight into HTTP state code, I will research more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Validator for add custom code during validator fails.

For that you can try with this way:

> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => $validator->errors(),
        ], 400);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've been trying for while, this helps me a lot

Comment: If this answer helps you then you can mark as correct answer and upvote this for other developers too.